# get specific element of an table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable

hello every one I am trying to get a specific element in my table and add a class to it to make the red buttons green when an image is uploaded. But i can't get the specific row in my table. Any one a solution for this?

My code:

```
  <b-table hover
           :filter="filter"
           id="my-table"
           :bordered="bordered"
           :fields="fields"
           :items="items"
           :per-page="perPage"
           :current-page="currentPage"
           responsive
           striped
           small>
    <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
      <b-button id="btnImage" size="sm" @click="info(row.item, $event.target)" class="addModal mr-2" ref="addModal">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'image' ]" />
      </b-button>
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

If i do this:  var tr = document.getElementById("my-table").getElementsByTagName("tr"); I get the following output:
[image]

inside every tr is an element thats called innerText that reference to the id that you can see here in my table:[image]

But how do i get the specific row in my table and add an class to the button of that specific row?

Comment: `row.item` gives the current row

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim if i try this i get row is undifind. How can i do this. Do i need to give row.item from the html to my script ?

Comment: What is the class based on per row? My initial reaction to what you are saying is this should be tracked in data on the item, or row.

Can you expand on what you are trying to do with the row? A little more detail on what exactly you want to do would be helpful.

Comment: @jonnycraze I am trying to get the specific row then take the button of that row and add a class to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every one that needs it. I fixed the problem to give row.item as a parameter to my method very simple but is works great

Answer (score 0):

Use scoped field slots

```
<template v-slot:cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>
```

Refer https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots. I think it's well documented.